# Covariance everyrow in mysql

Tags: mysql, covariance

I want to do correlation in mysql.

I am confused about how to subtract the average of the column from every column (1-24)?

### Table:

[image: sampletable]

First of all, I tried to select every column with LOOP, then if succeed I'll begin to subtract them, but I failed in select every column.

### Code:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE i INT;
SET i:=1;
myloop: LOOP
    SELECT 'i' FROM test_correl2 AS DEM;
    SET i=i+1;
    IF i=25 then
    LEAVE myloop;
END IF;
END LOOP myloop;
SELECT @i;

END
```

Comment: If the table contains more than one row, what result do you expect? What is the PRIMARY KEY (or a UNIQUE KEY) in the table?

Answer (score 0):

you can create 2 stored procedures like below.
first one is to grab average of the columns and have that value stored in @average.
second one is to update the columns to subtract this @average from every column.

```
create procedure get_test_average()
begin
  set @i = 1;
  set @columns = '(';
  while @i < 3 do
    set @columns = CONCAT(@columns,'`',@i,'`+');
    set @i=@i+1;
  end while;
  set @columns = CONCAT(@columns,'`',@i,'`');
  set @columns = CONCAT(@columns,')');
  set @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ',@columns,'/',@i,' INTO @average FROM test_correl2 WHERE Nopel = 1151110;');
  prepare statement1 from @sql;
  execute statement1;
end/

create procedure subtract_average()
begin
  set @i = 1;
  set @columns = '';
  while @i < 3 do
    set @columns = CONCAT(@columns,'`',@i,'` = ','`',@i,'`-@average,');
    set @i=@i+1;
  end while;
  set @columns = CONCAT(@columns,'`',@i,'` = ','`',@i,'`-@average');
  set @sql = CONCAT('UPDATE test_correl2 SET ',@columns,' WHERE Nopel = 1151110;');
  prepare statement1 from @sql;
  execute statement1;
end/
```

and then call each stored procedure once.

```
call get_test_average();
call subtract_average();
```

[sqlfiddle of these stored procs and how they're called](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4821b/2)

In the example sqlfiddle here I am only doing 3 columns, you can change occurrences of `3` to `24` to fit your needs (there is an occurrence of `3` in each stored proc above).